# PHP $_SERVER as security issue

Tags: php, symfony, global-variables, xss, csrf

iam writing application that will deal with very sensitive data, like bank account numbers and such, so i need to secure it well.I dont realy have an issue, iam confused a bit.Iam using symfony framework, and i did setup a scanner that wil scan `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIES, $_REQUEST and $_SERVER global` variables, but there are a certain variables in $_SERVER that are holding values that are cosidered as attacks, for example this is the report i get when scaning `$_SERVER`

```
Affected tags: dt, id, lfi, xss, csrf

Variable: 6.MYSQL_HOME | Value: \xampp\mysql\bin
Tags: dt, id, lfi
Description: Detects specific directory and path traversal | Tags: dt, id, lfi | ID 11

Variable: 6.OPENSSL_CONF | Value: C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
Tags: dt, id, lfi
Description: Detects specific directory and path traversal | Tags: dt, id, lfi | ID 11

Variable: 6.PATH | Value: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\xampp\php
Tags: xss, csrf, dt, id, lfi
Description: Detects the IE octal, hex and unicode entities | Tags: xss, csrf | ID 9
Description: Detects specific directory and path traversal | Tags: dt, id, lfi | ID 11

Variable: 6.COMSPEC | Value: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Tags: dt, id, lfi
Description: Detects specific directory and path traversal | Tags: dt, id, lfi | ID 11
```

After some thinking a sort of solution from my point of view would be to pass to scanner only values that are not controlled by the server, are there any better solutions  ?
Btw. iam working on localhost, so maybe scanner wont report this when i deploy it on cloud, and i know that this site is for programming, and my question is not constructive, but in this case google was not my friend.

Comment: What's exactly "a scanner"? It it's a feature of the Symfony framework, you should probably add a symfony tag to the question.

Comment: No, its just third party library that i included in project, to be more precisly its PHP Intrusion Detection System

Comment: Are you talking about [PHP-IDS](http://phpids.org/) ?

Comment: Yea, i integrated PHP-IDS into my symfony project that i mention it before in question.